# connect oracle apex application to multiple databases

Tags: oracle-apex, weblogic, connection-pool

is there any simple way to connect an oracle apex application to another database other than apex admin database  (like using WebLogic data source).

I read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/21.4/aelig/configuring-REST-data-services.html#GUID-7BC77FAF-EA96-4361-8391-88A31005FF10)  but there are a lot of problem with that.

Run these commands
``

> java -jar ords.war setup --database AML2
> Enter number for [1] Basic  [2] TNS  [3] Custom URL [1]:3
> Enter the Custom JDBC URL:sys/Syspass//192.168.1.1:1521/AML2
>
> java -jar ords.war map-url --type base-path --workspace-id NEW_DB /NEW_DB AML2

``
And  get success message after executing each command but when create and execute new workspace and app in the specified path (NEW_DB) get this error

`The connection pool named: aml2_pu does not exist`

how to resolve this problem or is there any simple or clear way to define connection in a file or WebLogic data source.
thanks for your attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An APEX installation is *in* the database, it doesn't "connect to the database", there also isn't something like an "admin database" - as such, it cannot connect to other databases. Your apex application and the data for that application live in the same database instance.

However, if you want to work with data from other databases in your application you can of course do so. The "old way" is using database links, however, nowadays connecting over rest is the way to go.

The documentation you are referencing is for having ORDS pointing to multiple databases. It is possible to have a single ORDS installation point to multiple APEX instances - in a previous job we used to have dev/uat/int instance on the same ORDS instance. Each of those databases have their own apex installation.

Comment: thanks koen for your complete answer. I understand what you said but I want to develop an apex application that it's data live in another database . is it possible? in another words i want to seperate apex meta data from application data.

Comment: What is the reason for going with that approach ? Apex metadata is separated from the application data. It is stored in its own schema.  In Oracle database you separate data by storing it in other schemas within the same database, not by storing data in other databases. That is one of the core principles of the oracle database. Not working this way is going to make your application development a lot more complex.
As I said above, in order to work with data in other databases you can either work with database links (the old way) or with REST (Apex supports rest data sources).

Comment: because my application data are ready and stored in another database. with data source I can manage connection pooling and other aspect of connection.

Comment: The way to implement this is to install apex in that database where your data is stored. You're treating it as a middleware application that can be installed elsewhere but that is not how apex works at all.